# Using more than 1 UINavigationController and only one UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I am having a problem with managing more than one `UINavigationControlller`.

I have a `UITabBar` and in every tab I have a separate `UINavigationController`. So If I switch in `UITabBar` by

```
tabBar.selectedIndex = i; // where i is index of tabbar.
```

and when I go back to previous tab by

```
tabBar.selectedIndex = previousIndex;
```

I go to the root of the `UINavigationController`, not the viewcontroller which I left previously.

I want to go to the viewcontroller from which I jump to another tab, without calling `-viewDidLoad:` or `-viewWillAppear:`.

I need a method which show either `UINavigationController` or my viewController.

Comment: this is a default functionality of UITabBar, unless we make any changes to show rootView... u might written some thing in tabBarDelegate to show rootView..

Comment: are you using any of the tabbarDelegate methods from [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTabViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) then please share the code

Comment: ok, i am checking my tabbardelegate. @vishy

Answer (score 0):

The following method when implemented in your AppDelegate.m file will be fired whenever u try to switch the tabs

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tbc shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

}
```

specify in your appDelegate class as the delagate of your tabbarcontroller

ie.( TabBarController.delegate = self) in appDidFinishLaunching method